# identifying a mtb frame

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

about one or two years ago my brother has brought this bike home and i am now thinking of restoring it. It has an alloy frame unsure of the size but the wheels are 27.5", feels strong and solid... But i just don't know if it's worth investing in it... hopefully you guys know what it is.  Thanks for your time and help.[image: Sorry for poor quality, that's all i could get for now.]

Comment: Based on the condition of the forks and rust on the chain/chain rings, its not worth spending money or time on it unless its for sentimental or educational reasons. At a minimum it needs new forks which are hundreds of dollars and rear brake.

Comment: It’s a generic budget alloy MTB. It might have had a name brand before the blue paint. Signals are plastic pedals, cable brakes , rusty elastomer forks. Check the brake pads, lube the chain and check all the bolts then get out and ride. Spend as little as you can on this bike. Restore no, use yes.

Comment: Just as i was thinking, not worth the time. Just felt the need to ask any way, Thanks guys and take care, i will be popping back when i get something that's worth the time.

Comment: Any bike is better than no-bike.  And this one could quite happily run as a beater bike for normal utility cycling.  The dirty rattle-can paint job is effective at hiding any identifying marks, but it doesn't stand out as a fancy bike.   Looks like the rear brake is missing its cable, rotor and perhaps the left hand lever ?   I'd do basic maintenance on it, get a lock, fix the brake and perhaps fit a rack, and use it go get around.    Probably not good for stunt riding, but a docile offroad trail would be totally OK.  The fork has probably deteriorated in its "bounce"